# ¿Dónde ubicar para ejecutar un script que llame a módulos desde la misma carpeta?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy buscando ejecutar un script de python que llame a los scripts desde la misma carpeta. Sin embargo no sé a qué nivel me tengo que poner para ejecutarlo. De hecho, cuando ejecuto el script en el nivel de su carpeta, tengo los siguientes errores:

```
antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/jom/scraper (master) $ python3 scraper_run.py                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper_run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scraper.scraper_sephora_USA import sephora_usa
antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/jom/scraper (master) $ ls
common.py  config.py  consistency_checks.py  constants.py  scraper_jom_london.py  scraper_run.py  scraper_sephora_USA.py
```

Incluso con un archivo `__init__.py` y incluso cuando intento hacerlo desde `~/environment/jom/`:

```
antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/jom (master) $ python scraper/scraper_run.py 
  File "scraper/scraper_run.py", line 37
    logger.info(f"scraping: {perfume_type}, {perfume_name}, {perfume_id}")
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/jom (master) $ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/jom (master) $ python3 scraper/scraper_run.py                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper/scraper_run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scraper.scraper_sephora_USA import sephora_usa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scraper'
antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/jom (master) $ ls
Makefile  README.md  convert-attribute-emoticlaims-mapping.py  docs  frontend  jom  notebooks  scraper  setup.py
```

Aqui esta el script:

```
import click
import os
from scraper.scraper_sephora_USA import sephora_usa
from scraper.scraper_jom_london import jomalone
from scraper.common import load_fragrances, save_to_json
from scraper.constants import SEPHORA_USA_PATH, JOM_LONDON_PATH, SAVE_PATH
from scraper.config import logger

from jom.products import productKey


@click.command()
@click.option("-s", "--site",
              required=True,
              help="sephora_usa / jomalone")
@click.option("-f", "--filter",
              multiple=True,
              default=[],
              help="multiple choice of fragrance id to scraping")
def run_scraper_sephora(site, filter):
    sites_data = {"sephora_usa": {"path": SEPHORA_USA_PATH,
                                  "func": sephora_usa}}
    logger.info("loading fragrances data")
    df = load_fragrances(sites_data[site]["path"])

    if len(filter) != 0:
        df = df[df["id"].isin(filter)]
    for i, product in df[df["id"].notna()].iterrows():
        perfume_name = product["name"]
        perfume_id = product["id"]
        perfume_type = product["type"]

        name_key = productKey(perfume_name)
```

Comment: Si está todo en la misma carpeta te puedes saltar lo que antecedente al nombre del módulo, o sea, `from scraper_sephora_USA import sephora_usa`.

Comment: No quiero modificar el script. Entonces entiendo que el script fue escribido para ser ejecutado en el la carpeta principal. Lo había probado con Python2, funciona pero no con Python3. ¿Cuál es la razón de esta diferencia @CandidMoe ?

Comment: Sin ver el script no puedo opinar.

Comment: Por seguro @CandidMoe , acabo de anadirlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La estructura de tu aplicación es la siguiente:

```
~/environment/jom/scraper
      scraper_run.py
      scraper_sephora_USA.py
```

por lo tanto, los `imports` deben hacerse sin indicar path, sin importar desde donde lo invoques, ya que el `import` es relativo al módulo.

*scraper_run.py*

```
from scraper_sephora_USA import sephora_usa

print(sephora_usa)
```

*scraper_sephora_USA.py*

```
sephora_usa = 5
```

**Ejecución desde directorio anterior**

```
python scraper/scraper_run.py
```

produce:

```
5
```

**Ejecución desde directorio scraper**

```
cd scraper
python scraper_run.py
```

produce:

```
5
```

Nota: El `print` no es una función en Python 2.7, motivo por el cual es inválido encerrar los argumentos entre paréntesis.

Comment: Muchas gracias Candid Moe ! Y me disculpa para el tiempo para acceptar. He eliminado todas las referencias al PATH. Sin embargo ahora intento llamar a un script en una otra carpeta. Intento hacerlo relativamente con un archivo en un otro modulo `from jom.config import DATA_PATH` pero ahora me contesta: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jom'` Tambien intente `import jom` pero no funciona